# Number-only switch

Tags: code-golf, open-ended-function, printable-ascii

Write a function that takes an ASCII-printable-only (all charcodes ∈ [32..126]) string input `x` and provides an ASCII-printable-only output string `f(x)`, such that for every x

- `f(f(x))=x`
- `f(x)` is all-numeric (all charcodes ∈ [48..57]) iff `x` is not all-numeric

You can assume input is not empty and never provide empty output, or treat empty input as "all-numeric". Shortest code in each language wins.

Some examples of "not all-numeric":

```
abc
a1b2c3
a333333
```

Comment: Trivially, (x↦x) is self-inverse and number-out-iff-number-in.

Comment: @RomanCzyborra Requirement: number-out-iff-NOT-number-in

Comment: i wanna answer https://tio.run/##JY2xDsIgFAD3fgUxNDyWZ1dNcXN0dmialMBrSqRIEJPq4K8jxu2Gu9yiHzfyvhSjYCFtUeLsfKbUWDWITiCKgxgbUrDqeGHOqr6XCD0/DR3iWG3vIksUvTM6UzOzTRnYq02iAfK0skpvF68uLwAYn4lqfpQSiFnJ/y/Q4QVTuOdzDSYrJadBsN/7I8ayahdUTC5kPu/adle@

Comment: a self-inverse bijection between all all-digits strings and all some-non-digit strings.

Answer (score 9):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) -Ṡ flag, <s>41</s> <s>40</s> <s>34</s> 30 bytes

```
λ[±[‹n⌊₇τCṅkQ↔|fC₇βnṪ]:xn≠ß_;†
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuaAiLCIiLCLOu1vCsVvigLlu4oyK4oKHz4RD4bmFa1HihpR8ZkPigofOsm7huapdOnhu4omgw59fO+KAoCIsIiIsIjEyOSJd) or [verify all test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuaAiLCLilqHGm2AgPT4gYG4iLCLOu1vCsVvigLlu4oyK4oKHz4RD4bmFa1HihpR8ZkPigofOsm7huapdOnhu4omgw59fO+KAoCIsIlfhuYU74oGLIiwiYWJjXG4xNjAxODkxXG5hMWIyYzNcbjMzNDYyNTQzMTE4NTlcbmEzMzMzMzNcbjQyODM3NjY1NjIzOTAyN1xueFxuMTIwLVxuMTAzNTg1ODM3LVxuNDU1NDMyOTM5ODAyMjg0ODQxOTAxXG4xMDM1ODU4MzdcbjEyMFxuMDAwMDFcbjAwMDAxLVxuOVxuOS0iXQ==)

This uses two injections to generate a bijection. The first injection \$f\$ from numeric to non-numeric is `‹` (append "-") and the second \$g\$ from non-numeric to numeric is `fC₇β` (get ascii values and convert from base 128). It is similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem#Proof but we make sure that there are no doubly infinite sequences or cyclic sequences by carefully choosing \$f\$ and \$g\$.

It works reasonably well for large inputs.

The simplified algorithm is the following:

```
def encode(S):
    if S is numeric:
        if there is a non-numeric T such that encode(T) == S:
            return T
        else:
            return f(S)
    else:
        if there is a numeric T such that encode(T) == S:
            return T
        else:
            return g(S)
```

Full explanation:

```
λ             # start a lambda
 [            # base case for recursion, only continue if the argument is not empty
  ±           # is the argument numeric?
   [          # if it is:
```

Compute `f(S)` and find the only candidate for `T`

```
‹             #   append "-"
 n            #   push argument
  ⌊           #   convert string to number
   ₇τ         #   convert to base 128
     C        #   chr(x)
      ṅ       #   join by nothing
       kQ↔    #   only keep printable ASCII
|             # else:
```

Compute `g(S)` and find the only candidate for T

```
f             #   list of characters
 C            #   ord(x)
  ₇β          #   convert from base 128
    n         #   push argument
     Ṫ        #   remove tail
]             # end if

:             # duplicate T candidate
 x            # compute encode(T)
  n≠          # is not equal to argument
    ß_        # if true pop
      ;†      # end lambda and call it
```

Comment: Couldn't the base 128 conversion lead to a numeric value?

Comment: @mousetail If a numeric N is the result of base 128 encode of a numeric M then encode(M) != N because encode(M) is either M with "-" appended or some shorter non-numeric so encode(N) is N with "-" appended.

Comment: You may want to explicitly mention the input will always be taken as a string. I noticed `±` is truthy for inputs like `1.29`. `+2` or `1e2`, but it seems to be correctly falsey for strings `"1.29"`, `"+2"`, and `"1e2"`, yet still beneficially truthy for string `"123"`.

Comment: Also, why is `kQ↔` necessary? Your test suite seems to run fine without it, but I assume it's for some kind of edge case not covered by the tests in the test suite? (EDIT: I can't edit my comment above anymore, but I see the flag `Ṡ` is used to ensure the input is always a string.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen If `kQ↔` is not there, some numbers will become unprintable ascii, e. g. 9 => \t. Also the Ṡ flag is supposed to make sure that all inputs are taken as string.

Comment: @AndrovT Regarding the `kQ↔` removing a potential `\t`: isn't it possible that encodings like `\tABC` and `ABC` are considered equal, where one of the two gives an incorrect output? (Also, do you have an input example where it would give a different output without the `kQ↔`?)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen An example is `9` => `9-` => `9` with `kQ↔` and `9` => `\t` => `9` without it. The problem asks only about ASCII printable strings so `\tABC` is an invalid input. Ragardless `\tABC` => `20476259` => `20476259-` because it attempts to decode `20476259` using the base 128 decoding which results in `\tABC`. Then it removes the tab and encodes `ABC` which results in `1073475`. `1073475` != `20476259` so it falls back to appending `-`.

Comment: @AndrovT Ah ok, that makes sense. The `kQ↔` is to ensure all integer input will get the trailing `-`. For a moment I thought it was for the non-integer inputs. Thanks for the explanation. And nice answer btw!

Comment: Seems to throw an error on numeric input with leading zeros.

Comment: @CursorCoercer Thanks, it's fixed now. I totally didn't spend 40 minutes looking for a built-in that converts strings to numbers.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>37</s> <s>36</s> <s>33</s> 32 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žQ∞δã˜Dʒ9ÝKĀ}sþI9ÝKĀis}ÅΔI‚1ìË}è
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7ARx3zzm05vPj0HJdTkywPz/U@0lBbfHifJ4SZWVx7uPXcFM9HDbMMD6853F17eMX//4q2AA) or [verify some test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WeWilvZLCo7ZJCkr2/4/uC3zUMe/clsOLT89xOTXJ8vBc7yMNtcWH9x1aB2FnFtcebj035dC6Rw2zDA@vOdxde3jFf53/0UoKSjpKBko6CkqJQIaJKYilqAgSMzcEsc3MzIAcdSsQ28DSEshWtFWKBQA) (times out for most test cases).

**Explanation:**

Pairs all *all-numeric* strings with all *ASCII-printable-only-not-all-numeric* strings. If the input is all-numeric, outputs the corresponding ASCII-printable-only-not-all-numeric, or vice-versa if not.

```python
žQ        # Push a builtin string of all printable ASCII
  ∞       # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
   δ      # Apply double-vectorized:
    ã     #  Cartesian power
     ˜    # Flatten this infinite list of lists
D         # Duplicate it
 ʒ    }   # Filter it by:
  9Ý      #  Push list [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    K     #  Remove all those digits from the string
     Ā    #  Python-style truthify to check if anything remains (aka NOT all-numeric)
          #  (Note: `d≠` or `DþÊ` wouldn't work here for test cases like 0.1 or +1)
s         # Swap, so the other infinite list is at the top again
 þ        # Only keep all all-numeric values
I         # Push the input
 9ÝKĀi }  # Pop, and if it's NOT all-numeric (with a similar check as in the filter):
      s   #  Swap the two infinite lists on the stack
ÅΔ     }  # Pop the top list, and find the first index that's truthy for:
  I‚      #  Pair the current value with the input
    1ì    #  Prepend a 1 before each (workaround, since "02"=="+2"=="2.0"==2 in 05AB1E)
      Ë   #  Check that both values in the pair are the same
        è # Get the value at the found index from the other infinite list
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See all pairs in the infinite lists.](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9vc2FiaWX//8W@aMW@UeKAmuKIns60w6PigqzLnGDKkjnDnUvEgH3DuP//)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 153 bytes

```hs
c=(head.).filter
d=['0'..'9']
e=(mapM id=<<).(<$>[0..]).flip replicate
f x=c(/=x).c(elem x).zipWith((.pure).(:))(e d)$filter(any(`notElem`d))$e[' '..'~']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2xDsIgFAD3fgUxNDyWZ1dNcXN0dmialMBrSqRIEJPq4K8jxu2Gu9yiHzfyvhSjYCFtUeLsfKbUWDWITiCKgxgbUrDqeGHOqr6XCD0/DR3iWG3vIksUvTM6UzOzTRnYq02iAfK0skpvF68uLwAYn4lqfpQSiFnJ/y/Q4QVTuOdzDSYrJadBsN/7I8ayahdUTC5kPu/adle@)

enumerates all all-decimals and all some-non-decimal strings and pairs them for lookup to bypass "0001"→base94(1)→"1" or n→all-decimals-base94(n)→base94(base94(n)) mismatches

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>172</s> 168 bytes

*Edit: -4 bytes thanks to pajonk*

```r
\(x,`?`=unlist,m=match){d=?Map(f<-\(n)if(n)?lapply(intToUtf8(32:126,T),paste0,f(n-1)),1:(2*nchar(x)))
a=d[e<-grepl("^\\d*$",d)]
`if`(i<-m(x,b<-d[!e],0),a[i],b[m(x,a)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PU_BToQwFLzzFVg99G3aZMFEN4SGL_C2ngDDg7ZuE8Cm7Sob45d4wYPRX_JvZIPx8t5k3mRm3vuHm7_8iwndQXweg-a7n--KTqwpGnEce-MDG8SAyxlepSju0FKd84qOYPQyih6t7U_UjGH_dB_0jl6nWZLesD0wiz6oLVtkPAFgSUbTzdgd0NEJACIUslQ5f3TK9pQ8VJXcXBEmoY4aoxtqcj4sPdqcy_JC1WwLDEtTs7Y80wg1vP31zS7jZ-VOcYvedHHCzxHYBeViNeFge-WzaP2QEiTwj28JrA7zvO5f)
or [Attempt a simpler version](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY_PToNAEIfvPMWIHnabJWGrxkogfQLjwXoCDMP-kU3oQmCJbYxP4qUefAAfp29TGjTBy0y-mcmX33x-dYfj0yV0Sg5CSejfjBMV6MEKZxoLI1aAdVthqRw0Ghpb70FU2KFwqusjCIHDEq4BoQQB0psMyffgdLA6_mRkx4p1kQy2Nr1j22SL45q-y2T9gC3RcZARS40ey7rGtq33xFi3aZ6dXhFBblbRLWf3dxEPQ8o2lLXYOxWy8T7glDIekeXCnvOQHaXUw0SmKg5eO9XWxH_JMrm48pmkuVcYXRATB9sxUBkHMr1QORudmJqclel5jDSnH7_BH6c_iI-lT70_4MsZhPwfzImL-epsmLSHw9RP)

**How? - ungolfed code**

```
switch=function(x){
    f=function(n)if(n)unlist(lapply(c(intToUtf8(32:126,T)),paste0,f(n-1)))
        # f is a recursive function that generates all 'words' of size n
    d=unlist(lapply(1:(2*nchar(x)),f))
        # d is the 'dictionary' of all words of size 1..n
        # using a max size of twice the length of input
    e=grepl("^[0-9]*$",d)
        # e is the indices of all-number words
    a=d[e]
        # a is the set of all-number words
    b=d[!e]
        # b is the set of mixed all-letter or number-letter words
    `if`(i<-match(x,b,0),a[i],b[match(x,a)])
        # if the input matches an all-number word, get its index i, 
        # and return the mixed word at the corresponding index;
        # otherwise vice-versa
}
```

Comment: [-4 bytes?](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PU_BToQwFLzzFVg99G3aZMFEN4SGL_C2ngDDg7ZuE8Cm7Sob45d4wYPRX_JvZIPx8t5k3mRm3vuHm7_8iwndQXweg-a7n--KTqwpGnEce-MDG8SAyxlepSju0FKd84qOYPQyih6t7U_UjGH_dB_0jl6nWZLesD0wiz6oLVtkPAFgSUbTzdgd0NEJACIUslQ5f3TK9pQ8VJXcXBEmoY4aoxtqcj4sPdqcy_JC1WwLDEtTs7Y80wg1vP31zS7jZ-VOcYvedHHCzxHYBeViNeFge-WzaP2QEiTwj28JrA7zvO5f)

Comment: @pajonk - Thanks (x2 for both improvements!)